# .htaccess point back to a php file which is in the middle of the URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have been looking around but could completely find what I am looking for even though I am sure its a very basic task. I am looking to have to so that the URL can be something like this "www.site.com/server/1". The server part in the URL will be the .php file which will then be able to use the number after the / in queries etc.

I have it sorted so that it doesn't need the .php but can't work out how to rewrite? back to the search.php file (not every sure if rewrite is what I am looking for.)

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+) /$1.php?number=$2 [L,QSA]
```

You'll need to replace the query-string parameter name `number` with what you need. Not sure what you mean by "be able to use the number after the / in queries".

Comment: Works thanks but do you have any idea how to get it so I don't need the .php after server as my current setup causes it to be sent to error.php (/server/1 doesn't work if I have my rewrite on, as it thinks it's going to a missing file called '1' but /server.php/1 works fine)